# where am I going going wrong in my calculations to get largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers?

Tags: python, combinations

I am doing the project Euler problems to help me understand the maths behind algorithms as suggested by somebody on here.
I don't want the code I just want a push in the right direction to figure out where I am going wrong.

```
def genYieldThreeValues(stop):

    j = 999
    while stop >99 and j > 99:
        multiples = str(stop * j)
        front = multiples[:3] # get front three numbers
        back = multiples[-3:] # get last three numbers
        stop-=1
        j-=1
        yield  [front,back,multiples] # yield a list with first three, last three and all numbers


def highestPalindrome(n):

    for x in genYieldThreeValues(n):
        if   x[1] ==x[0][::-1]: # compare first three and last three digits reversed
            return x[2]         # if they match return value

print(highestPalindrome(999))
```

(EDIT: New code)

```
def genYieldThreeValues(stop):
while stop >99:
    yield stop

def highestPalindrome(n):
highest = 0
for x in range(genYieldThreeValues(n).next(),99,-1):
    for i in range(x,99,-1):
        product = str(x*i)
        if product[::-1]  == product and product > highest:
            if len(product) > 5:
                highest = product
return highest
```

Answer (score 1):

You are decrementing both `stop` and `j` in the same loop, so that you only generate the squares `999*999`, `998*998`, `997*997`, etc. Without studying your code further, I *think* what you want is to leave `stop` constant in `genThreeValues`, and instead use that generator with multiple values of `stop`.

Comment: Thanks, chepner, I got the answer correct eventually but not in a very elegant or efficient way. I will sleep on it and try improve in tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: Added working code, could you give me any pointers on how i can  improve the efficiency? it is taking roughly 700ms to return the correct value